# how to set slide proportions with ReporteRs package

Tags: r, reporters

I started to play with the `ReporteRs` package and hanging at a simple problem. I am trying to get a specific format for ma slides, for example to present on a 1280x1024 projector without any bars... But the slides created by `ReporteRs` have strange dimensions. Is there a way to set the size of the slides somehow?

Here is the example code:

```
require(ReporteRs)
require(ggplot2)

myplot <- qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, 
               data=iris, color=Species, 
               size=Petal.Width, alpha=I(0.7))

# Create a new document
mydoc <- pptx(title="EVG demo")

mydoc <- addSlide(mydoc, "Content with Caption")
mydoc <- addTitle(mydoc, "Vector graphics format versus raster format")
mydoc <- addPlot(mydoc, function() print(myplot), vector.graphic=TRUE)
mydoc <- addPlot(mydoc, function() print(myplot), vector.graphic=FALSE)

writeDoc(mydoc, file="EVG_example.pptx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just figured it out on my own. I saved an empty PowerPoint document with the expected ratios as `template.pptx` and used this when using function `pptx()`...

```
myplot <- qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, 
               data=iris, color=Species, 
               size=Petal.Width, alpha=I(0.7) )

# Create a new document
mydoc <- pptx(title="EVG demo", template='template.pptx')

mydoc <- addSlide(mydoc, "Content with Caption")
mydoc <- addTitle(mydoc, "Vector graphics format versus raster format")
mydoc <- addPlot(mydoc, function() print(myplot), vector.graphic=TRUE)
mydoc <- addParagraph(mydoc, 'test test 1 2 3')

writeDoc(mydoc, file="EVG_example.pptx")
```

Comment: @DavidGohel   Yeah, actually I figured it out two hours after I wrote this, that all I was asking is in your documentation... By the way, great package!